# Typescript build Sublime Text 3 on Linux - [Errno 20] Not a directory

Tags: linux, typescript, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Trying to make build system for TypeScript working on Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu.

When running

```
tsc
```

on terminal it works fine. (Prints Version 1.5.0-beta
Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ...])

And when running:

```
which tsc
```

it says:

```
/home/antti/npm/bin/tsc
```

However, when building ts file on ST3 builder it says:

```
[Errno 20] Not a directory
[cmd: ['tsc', '/home/antti/code/greeter.ts']]
[dir: /home/antti/code]
[path: /home/antti/npm/bin/tsc]
[Finished]
```

Here's my Typescript.sublime-build config file:

```
{
   "cmd": ["tsc","$file"],
   "file_regex": "(.*\\.ts?)\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)\\)\\:\\s(...*?)$",
   "selector": "source.ts",      
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/Phaiax/ArcticTypescript ?It helps a lot with typescript development in sublime. It also uses the tsconfig.json file that will become "standard" for working with typescript in most editors.

Comment: Indeed very helpful package. Works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `path` key in your config file like this:

```
{
   "cmd": ["tsc","$file"],
   "file_regex": "(.*\\.ts?)\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)\\)\\:\\s(...*?)$",
   "selector": "source.ts",
   "path": "/home/antti/npm/bin/"
}
```

The important part is not to point to the executable (`.../bin/tsc`) but to the directory (`.../bin/`).

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu Install the package "nodejs-legacy" using  `- sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

After that edit the content of tsc file in "usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/"  using

```
- sudo gedit /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc

as   #!/usr/bin/env nodejs

require('./tsc.js')
```

It worked for me.